# Playwright: "Test Timeout Exceeded Error" when 5 or 6 similar type of test cases are included in one file

Tags: typescript, error-handling, automation, timeout, playwright

So, I am writing automation script in playwright using TypeScript. Each of the testcases are running perfectly but when I try to execute more similar testcases at once, it is showing Timeout error after executing 2/3 testcases. I want to know the approach of how I can write multiple testcases on a single file without having any timeout issues. I am attaching some example code snippets.

```
import { test, expect, Locator } from '@playwright/test';
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

let businessSidebar: Locator;
let search: Locator;
let advanceFilter: Locator;

test.beforeEach(async({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('/');
    
    //login
    await page.locator("input[name='email']").fill('admin@gmail.com');
    await page.locator("input[name='password']").fill('admin');
    await page.locator("button:text('Login')").click();

    businessSidebar = page.locator('text=Business Profile');
    await businessSidebar.click();

    search = page.locator("input[name='search']");
    advanceFilter = page.locator("//button[text()='Filters']")

})


test.skip('Verify user can filter business profile by: Industries', async({ page }) => {
    const industryFilter = await page.locator("(//button[contains(@class,'flex w-full')])[1]");
    await industryFilter.click();

    const select = await page.locator("//span[text()='Agriculture and Fisheries']");
    await select.click();

    await expect(page).toHaveURL(`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/business`);
})

test.skip('Verify user can filter business profile by: Business Type', async({ page }) => {
    const businessTypeFilter = await page.locator("(//button[contains(@class,'flex w-full')])[2]");
    await businessTypeFilter.click();

    const select = await page.locator("//span[text()='Association']");
    await select.click();

    await expect(page).toHaveURL(`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/business`);
})
```

These testcases are running perfectly. The error occurs after adding 2/3 more similar type of testcases. The timeout is occurs in the `befoEach()` scope.

My timeout is set as below. I have also tried to increase the timeout.

```
timeout: 40 * 1000,
  expect: {
    /**
     * Maximum time expect() should wait for the condition to be met.
     * For example in `await expect(locator).toHaveText();`
     */
    timeout: 5000
  },
```

I tried using waitForTimeout() in every testcases but the result remains the same. I am asking for an approch so that I can solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try making all those global variables local so that each test is idempotent? Otherwise, different tests running in parallel share locators, potentially corrupting state. Also, tests should not rely on any particular ordering--they should be self-contained. I suspect your login test is performing actions that need to come before later tests. That logic should probably be moved to a `beforeEach` block.

Comment: I tried to make all the global variables local and kept only the login part in the `beforeEach` block but no luck with that. The issue still persists.